# How to import non-standard-library packages use gccgo

Tags: go, gccgo

First of all, all these code can be built successfully using go tool(e.g. go build, go install)

For say I got an a.go which tries to import a non-standard-library pkg from github:

```
package a

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/usr/pkg"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Import pkg", pkg.somevar)
}
```

when I try to compile it with gccgo:

```
$ gccgo -c a.go
a.go:5:20: error: import file ‘github.com/usr/pkg’ not found
...
```

And then I read the [Setting up and using gccgo](http://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo) , it says

> When you import the package FILE with gccgo, it will look for the
>   import data in the following files, and use the first one that it
>   finds.
>
> FILE.gox
>   FILE.o
>   libFILE.so
>   libFILE.a
>
> The gccgo compiler will look in the current directory for import files

So I cp the $GOPATH/pkg/github.com/usr/pkg.a to the current directory and rename it as libpkg.a.

It seems failed again:

```
$ gccgo -c a.go
a.go:9:4: error: libpkg.a: malformed archive header name at 8
a.go:9:4: error: libpkg.a exists but does not contain any Go export data
```

And yes, I use gccgo 4.7.2

I've got no experience woking with gcc, so I search for some help here.

Comment: What is a "non-standard pkg from github"? Anyway, is it possible to use the standard "go get" for it or not? If not, why is it so?

Comment: sorry for my poor english, I mean pkgs not in go standard library. I will fix my post. thx

Comment: I don't think you can use the `.a` files compiles with the normal go toolchain, you'll need to recompile the package with `ggcgo` I would have thought.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood yes, i've thought about that. As you can see above, I'm unable to build a single go file, so I don't know how to recompile the package with gccgo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the go command from the gc distribution, and run `go build -compiler gccgo .`

Your idea of copying pkg.a does not work because pkg.a was not built with gccgo.

Comment: How to build the `go` tool from gc distribution on platform where only gccgo is available?